# Expo Barcode Scanner stop working after navigate screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So, I'm facing a problem when I navigate to my scanner screen and go back the previous screen, then navigate again to my scanner screen, barcode scanner does not working. even console logs does not working. I have to clear cashe and all data from expo app in order to work scanner screen again. I really don't know what causing the porblem but highly suspicious about Navigation. Can anyone help me pls?
Im adding my Scanner Screen right below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import axios from "axios";
import { localIP, ngrokServer } from "../constants";
import allStyles from "../components/molecules/Styles";

const styles = allStyles;

export default function ScannerScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReset(false);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    console.log("Data: ", data);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.scannerScreenContainer}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
      {scanned && reset && (
        <Button title={"Tap to Scan Again"} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />
      )}
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'm using axios.post and thought maybe that was the cause of problem but when I removed that code block and run again it doesn't scan the QR code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding a listener for focus events (emitted when the screen comes into focus).

This is what it looks like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something - for example: reset states, ask for camera permission
      setScanned(false);
      setHasPermission(false);
      (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted"); 
      })();
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

Try using this code and see if it works.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener

Comment: This works perfectly! I still wonder if this solution has any impact in the performance of the app. Do you have any thoughts on that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you came out with that? Do you know why by resetting the permissions to solve the problem? thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on expo, solved it with Miztory's solution. I just had to

```
import { useNavigation } from 'expo-router';
```

and

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
```

the rest is the same. Thank you @Miztory